# Make stuff optional but without capture

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

In regex () brackets are used to capture stuff, and ? is used to make stuff optional

`(... (...) ... )?`

Can I make it optional but without using the brackets? I only want to capture some text from inside, not the whole thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a non-capturing group:

```
...(?:...)?...
```

Comment: I did it wth ...?(...)?...?

Comment: That's completely different.

Comment: I think u misunderstood the q. I want that whole thing to be optional, but only capture the contents of the inner bracket

Comment: (?:... (...) ... )? works too. Thanks I now understand how non capturing groups work:)